# .net core 2.0 generated simple console application error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, console-application

I'm using windows 10 and visual studio 2017 to generated simple console application for .net core 2.0 framework. In the app I'm trying to show

> MessageBox.Show("Test msg");

```
    using System;
    using System.Windows.Forms; // error

    namespace Window
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
                MessageBox.Show("Message from main (primary) thread"); // error
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

In the generated project it adds dependencies SDK -> Microsoft.NETCore.App -> System.Windows.dll.

Why do I still get this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows Forms is not part of .NET Core. Windows Forms is part of the .NET Framework . You would need to pick a GUI library implemented on top of .NET Core or switch to using .NET Framework if you still want to use Windows Forms. Refer to the diagram below.

[image]